# Odoo, how get supplier Price value from supplierinfo, in custom module?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm a odoo 13 user (not developer).
In a custom module which add products lines in Purchase Order, I need to add:  product_id, name, price_unit , taxes_id.
product_id, name, taxes_id  values are available in product.product and I can get its value with this code:

```
'product_id': product.id,
'name': product.name,
'taxes_id': product.supplier_taxes_id,
```

but 'price_unit' value is in product.supplierinfo (it's supplier price) and if I use code:

```
'price_unit':  supplierinfo.price
```

I have error:   NameError: name 'supplierinfo' is not defined

What's my mistake? How I can get Supplier Price value from product.supplierinfo and assign it to 'price_unit'???

I'm not developer and I don't know how create code, please any suggestion it's appreciated with code.
Thanks
Below complete code:

```
    def _add_product(self, product, qty, price):
        corresponding_line = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.product_id.id == product.id)
        if corresponding_line:
            corresponding_line[0].product_qty += float(qty)
            corresponding_line[0].price_unit = float(price) or supplierinfo.price
        else:
            self.order_line += self.order_line.new({
                'product_id': product.id,
                'product_qty': qty,
                'date_planned': fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now() - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)),
                'name': product.name,
                'product_uom': product.uom_id.id,
                'price_unit': float(price) or supplierinfo.price,       
                'taxes_id': product.supplier_taxes_id,
            })
        return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code,

```py
    def _add_product(self, product, qty, price):
        corresponding_line = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.product_id.id == product.id)
        # My Cust Start
        supplierinfo = product.mapped('seller_ids')[:1]
        # My Cust End
        if corresponding_line:
            corresponding_line[0].product_qty += float(qty)
            corresponding_line[0].price_unit = float(price) or supplierinfo.price
        else:
            self.order_line += self.order_line.new({
                'product_id': product.id,
                'product_qty': qty,
                'date_planned': fields.Datetime.to_string(datetime.datetime.now() - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)),
                'name': product.name,
                'product_uom': product.uom_id.id,
                'price_unit': float(price) or supplierinfo.price,       
                'taxes_id': product.supplier_taxes_id,
            })
        return True
```

Thanks

Comment: Very good answer and only a little change in the code, but what about products with more than one supplier or multiple supplier entries (e.g. if a supplier offers volume pricing)?

Comment: Yes, right it take the first vendor price but in that, you can filter our the supplier to whom you want the price based on that you get the price. At the end, you have to fetch only the one vendor price. So, you can filter out the supplierinfo.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your help.  Thanks Dipen Shah, you code work perfect and currently it's the only code ready to use for me, that I'm not developer and I've not skills for create/edit code.

Comment: Thank Dani, If it works for you then you can upvote this answer/remarks which increases my profile strength. ;)

Comment: Hi Dipen Shah, In my other post about priceHistory, your post it was deleted. Can you see again it, I've updated code with a part I've forgot, and post a better explain. I would write you a message directly, but I think is not possible here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I interpreted your post correctly you yould just write

```py
'price_unit':  product.supplierinfo.price
```

as the `price` is an attribute of `supplierinfo` which is an attribute of `product`.

Comment: Hi Jakob, thanks but not work. I have error:  AttributeError: 'product.product' object has no attribute 'supplierinfo'

Comment: It is hard to tell what the structure of your program is like. Could you add the declaration of `product` to your question?

Comment: Thanks Jakob, I can understand to you. About "Could you add the declaration of product to your question?" what do you mean? What do you need to know? I'm not developer, I have not technical skills and I don't know what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Most of these things are already in Odoo, but some custom modules don't use them. Usually Odoo logic for prices, taxes and product description calculation is only triggered in the UI (browser) by onchange events. For example the product onchange event for purchase or sales order lines.

You or developers can use them very easily. Just set up a new purchase/sales order line with all required fields and trigger the method behind that event by yourself.

The following code is not a final implementation of your requirement, because the onchange method could change more values, you maybe think it would. But just change those values right afterwards to your desired ones, like i've done with `date_planned` and `name`.

```py
line = self.order_line.new({
    'product_id': product.id,
    'product_qty': qty,
    'product_uom': product.uom_id.id,
    'price_unit': 0.0,
    'order_id': self.id
})
line.onchange_product_id()
line.write({
    'date_planned': datetime.date.today() - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1),
    'name': product.name,
})
```

Comment: Hi CZoellner, thanks for help. I would like use your code, but I don't know how adapt it to my code. I'm new Odoo user only, I'm not a developer and I have not skills for edit/create code. I paid a developer for develop custom module, but he given me module with many bugs and is desappear. Module by barcode scanning in a new field, should to add product line with quantity 1 and default supplier price, or product with custom quantity and custom price. You can see in code "corresponding_line[0].product_qty += float(qty)
 corresponding_line[0].price_unit = float(price) or supplierinfo.price" ...

Comment: ...CONTINUE    I'm try myself to solve the most important bug, it's default supplier price (price_unit). Value is not get from supplier. If you can not write me exact code, which I can copy and paste, I don't know how use your explain, for apply it to price_unit bug. Thank you very much!!

Comment: It's difficult to present a full solution without knowing all of the code and all your business requirements in context of this custom module. And and I don't think that not using a real Odoo developer is good for you, because an ERP application is no hobby or anything like that, it's crucial for your business. Implementing new things shouldn't be taken lightly. Hopefully the solution of Dipen Shah is enough :-)